# eliminar palabras en php al encontrar un -

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente listado de datos de un `WHILE` en PHP

```
<?php
      $query   = "SELECT * FROM table where value='$thisvalue'";
      $result  = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $campo = $row['value'];
       //QUITAR PALABRAS SI ENCUENTRA UN - SOLO PALABRAS.
       echo $campo;
       }


    PANELEGP00001
    PANELEGP00003
    PANELEGP00001-1
    PANELEGP00002-TOS
    PANELEGP00004-2
    LIVOR-44_900_2100
```

Deseo poder quitar las palabras **SOLO LAS PALABRAS** al momento de encontrar un **-** . He buscando metodos en PHP intente con `str_replace` pero no he tenido resultados.

Me gustaria una resultado asi.

```
    PANELEGP00001
    PANELEGP00003
    PANELEGP00001-1
    PANELEGP00002   //SE QUITO LA PALABRA TOS
    PANELEGP00004-2
    LIVOR-44_900_2100
```

Comment: Ok... agrega el codigo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `explode` y `is_numeric` asi:

```
<?php

    $valores = array("PANELEGP00001",
    "PANELEGP00003",
    "PANELEGP00001-1",
    "PANELEGP00002-TOS",
    "PANELEGP00004-2",
    "LIVOR-44_900_2100"
  );

  foreach ($valores as $i => &$valor) {
      $palabras = explode("-", $valor);      
      if (isset($palabras[1]) && preg_match("/[a-z]/i", $palabras[1])) {          
          $valor = $palabras[0];
      }
  }
  var_dump($valores);

?>
```

Comment: Funciona muy bien pero tengo la siguiente duda. Si agregas este item a tu array `LIVOR-44_900_2100` en el listado me lo deja asi `LIVOR`

Comment: En ese caso es mejor `preg_match`, ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Thanks my budda funciono muy bien!!

Answer (score 0):

Creo que para esto lo mejor es utilizar preg_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) con un regular expression.
Por ejemplo, para buscar el texto que decis, en la linea que dice

```
//QUITAR PALABRAS SI ENCUENTRA UN - SOLO PALABRAS.
```

deberías poner

```
$campo = preg_replace('\-\D+', '', $campo);
```

¡Suerte!